# Delegates and events

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

What is the difference between

```
public delegate void SecondChangedHandler(Object clock, TimeInfoEventArgs ti);
public event SecondChangedHandler OnSecondChanged;
```

and

```
public event EventHandler<TimeInfoEventArgs> OnSecondChanged;
```

When should you use which and is there any best practice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before generics the first approach was the only option to declare an event handler delegate. Since generics were introduced in .NET 2.0, `EventHandler<T:EventArgs>` is the preferred way. Semantically there is no difference between them.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference indeed. Then `EventHandler<T>` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx)) has just been added as a "shortcut" to avoid having to redeclare the delegate.

Comment: +1 - It is indeed to avoid having to redeclare the delegate.